# Why is my qt makefile overwritting my makefile after my switch from cvs to git?

Tags: git, qt, makefile, cvs

```
cvs version 1.11.22
git 1.7.41
qt 3.3.3
qt 3.3.6
Red Hawk 5.4.12 (from uname)
gmake (???? the machines in question are not connected to the internet and are hard to update)
```

so to prove that our transtion from cvs to git went well I made a build from a cvs checkout and one from a git checkout.

But now we notice that the git one was overwritten the qt makefile
both cvs and git repository have the correct file but only the git version shows that 
makefile is regenerated (and wrong).

Ideas on where to look?

Comment: Exactly how did you migrate from CVS to git? Any special configuration in the git repository?

Comment: Re: updating the machines: Can't you get a copy of the updates package repository to them, say via a DVD or a large pendrive? In many cases "misterious problems" had been long fixed upstream...

Comment: so after posing this question to the kind people here.  I go to the lab to look into it and I am having a hard time reproducing it yet I have some modified makefiles ????

Comment: @vonbrand we used some scripts to do the convert but the file looks good in the git repository but bad after a while  <br>  I do not have the power to do  updating I  have no root priviledge and need special permission to bring in software

Comment: the files in a git repository don't rot away, something is changing them. Any commands run when the file turns out damaged? Does `git checkout makefile` give the correct file? Perhaps building the stuff creates the makefile? Maybe the timestamp from `ls -l makefile` (when it was last modified)  gives a clue. If it turns out to be "old", that means that that copy was somehow checked out of git.

Comment: updating was just a suggestion; if it is not in your powers just keep in mind that that could be (part of) a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to reproduce the problem! This helped me to  determine it was only happening on a fresh git checkout and thus this is  was a cvs vs git problem.

When you check something out of cvs it has random dates for the files.  (I have never been about to figure out where the date of the file comes from in cvs.)

In git all the files have today's date on them.

So when qmake looked at the filename.pro it saw that it was newer than the Makefile and so the Makefile needed to be  regenerated.  When the Makefile was checked out again it now and a newer date than the filename.pro and the Makefile was not regenerated ever again.

So I can either delete the filename.pro so that qmake can't remake the Makefile 
OR
update the filename.pro to include the extra libraries that I need and Make the Makefile.